# Tainted canvas on Google Drive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am learning HTML and JavaScript and am practicing by hosting the HTML and image files on Google drive. I am drawing a color wheel to a canvas and using `getImageData` to get the RGB values from whichever pixel the mouse is over. The images and JavaScript are in the same folder and initially I successfully used `getImageData` whenever I previewed the HTML file, but now it only works sometimes. I haven't changed anything, but I noticed that when it doesn't work, the URL for the HTML file has a weird series of letters and numbers in it (`https://f#fff##FF#F#fff#.googledrive.com/host/folder/example.html` instead of `https://google.drive.com/host/folder/example.html`).

I also get the following error from the console:

> `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`

I think I understand the concept of a tainted canvas but I thought I would be able to use `getImageData` if the images and .js were in the same Google drive folder, and this method worked at first. I am confused as to why this doesn't work anymore and why the HTML url has changed, and I was wondering if there was a way to make it work while still hosting everything on Google drive. I am using both Google Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Probably because you can't be perfectly sure the files are all served from the same server within the google drive cloud.

Comment: Be sure you've configured your Google Drive "webserver" properly: http://www.cloudlock.com/blog/how-to-use-google-drive-as-a-web-server/

Comment: Thanks for your help, everyone. I've resigned to the fact that I can never guarantee the files will all be on the same server so I put the images on imgur and used this line `img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";` before stating the image source, according to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/naeluh/nsU5Q/